# Is HTTPS Handshake Data Included in Firebase Database Download Usage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've been prototyping an app that reports infrequent device-generated events (e.g. geofence transitions) and user requests to cloud functions.  It seemed like database triggers would be a secure, simple, and low-cost means to invoke the cloud functions.  The app packages the event/request parameters into a small object (<500 bytes) and writes the object to the Firebase DB, triggering the desired cloud function. This works well and provides the expected benefits.

As I scaled up my testing and looked at the database usage panel of the Firebase console, I saw that the size of downloaded data was much higher than I expected. My client-side code has no listeners; it only writes data. I checked that the cloud functions are only reading the expected small objects and the single query in the code is for data that has an index specified in the security rules.

I then starting looking at the network statistics provided by the [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html#network) for specific client-side events.  The data showed that when a database connection does not exist and needs to be established for a write to the server, roughly 4500 bytes of data are received.  Knowing little about HTTPS, I assumed this was Firebase overhead associated with the database connection and considered other options.

Next, I tried writing my trigger objects using my own OkHttpClient connection to the REST API.  When I saw the same 4000+ bytes being received for the writing of a 500 byte object, I realized that the received data must be the HTTPS handshake of certificates and keys and is likely unavoidable.

My questions are:

1. Is the 4000+ bytes received by the client when a connection to the Firebase database servers is established mostly the exchange of security data for the HTTPS connection?
2. Are these bytes considered "downloaded data" and therefore included in the usage total shown on the Firebase console and in the billing calculation?
3. If a cloud function uses `admin.database()` to access the Firebase database, is that SDK implemented using the REST API?  In that case, does the issue in question #2 apply there also?

As I indicated at the beginning of my post, the events/user-requests I am handling are infrequent.  It will almost always be the case that when data needs to be written to report an event, a DB connection will not exist and will need to be established.  If the answer to question #2 is yes, then the cost of an operation that was thought be less than 500 bytes will actually be 4000+ bytes.  For this use-case, it seems the lowest-cost way to report the events to cloud functions is to use [HTTP triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), not database triggers.

**Update:**

If I had searched the documentation more thoroughly, I would not have needed to post this question. It's all covered in the [Database Billing and Profiler documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing):

> - **Protocol overhead**: Some additional traffic between the server and clients is necessary to establish and maintain a session. Depending on
>     the underlying protocol, this traffic might include: Firebase Realtime
>     Database's realtime protocol overhead, WebSocket overhead, and HTTP
>     header overhead. Each time a connection is established, this overhead,
>     combined with any SSL encryption overhead, contributes to the
>     connection costs. Although this is typically not a large amount of
>     bandwidth, it can be substantial if your payloads are tiny or you make
>     frequent, short connections.
> - **SSL encryption overhead**: There is a cost associated with the SSL encryption overhead necessary for secure connections. On average, this
>     cost is approximately 3.5KB for the initial handshake, and
>     approximately 40B for TLS record headers on each outgoing message. For
>     most apps, this is a small percentage of your bill. However, this
>     could become a large percentage if your specific case requires a lot
>     of SSL handshakes. For example, devices that don't support TLS session
>     tickets might require large numbers of SSL connection handshakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of project specifics in your question, for which Stack Overflow may not be the best place to answer. I'll provide some simple answers below, but recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

---

HTTPS handshake bandwidth is billable traffic and should be shown in the database usage panel in the Firebase console. I'm don't know what the amount of overhead is.

The [Admin SDK for Node](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node) uses a socket to connect to the Firebase database. It does not use the REST API. Bandwidth while negotiating the HTTPS/WebSocket connection is billable traffic here too.

Building of this connection from Cloud Functions to the Database happens when a new container is created. This can be upon the first deploy of the project's functions, after a period of inactivity, or when the Cloud Functions needs to be scaled-up due to high activity.